# How do I use the gun in the Android port of Another World?

Tags: android, another-world

How do I use the gun in the Android version of Another World?

Based on the in-game help, I would have thought that tapping the screen would fire the gun and that pressing the screen longer would make the gun go into the other modes.  That lines up with what I remember from the Apple IIgs port from years ago (when the mouse button served a similar function, if I recall).  However, tapping the screen just moves my character.

What am I supposed to be doing instead?

Comment: Both the iOS and Android ports use the same “touch” controls by default, so this question can apply to both versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this review from Destructoid](http://www.destructoid.com/review-another-world-20th-anniversary-ios--212406.phtml), tapping on the *bottom-left* or *bottom-right* corner while holding a gun will fire. Holding down the corner will charge the other firing modes.

When not holding a gun, tapping the bottom corners will perform a kick. Tapping anywhere else continues to be for controlling Lester.

[image: info prompt for tapping bottom corner]

Comment: Good call -- it didn't occur to me to look for iOS port information.  Only the lower left corner activates the gun, it turns out.  The lower right corner kicks, which I already knew.  Also, your link does not work on desktop browsers.  If you would like to edit, I'd be glad to award the bounty.

Comment: Good catch! Link is fixed.